# Orthogonal Complements

Tags: functional-analysis

In a normed space $X$, the distance $\delta$ from a element $x\in X$ to a nonempty subset $M\subset X$ is defined to be $\delta= \inf_{\hat{y}\in M} ||x-\hat{y}||$. My lecture say: is important to know whether there is a $y\in M$ such that $\delta=  ||x-y||$, for example in the Figure (a), below, no exist such $y$ . My question is Why no exist such $y$? Why this $y$ is no at the most in left? [image]

Comment: $M$ is an *open* segment, the endpoints of the segment are not in $M$.

Comment: @DavidMitra, honestly I'm hating your style of answering questions in comments because: 1. If answer is non trivial it is worth to be an **answer** not a **comment**. If answer is trivail then defenitely there will be people who will post an answeer. When you answer question in comments other people hesite to post an **answer** because it looks like plagiarism. Please follow standards of MSE and don't use comments ad hoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at all sure what that little arrow in diagram (a) is supposed to indicate, so I'll just ignore it.

Note that if you choose any point $z\in M$, then there would be a point $y\in M$ with $y<z$ (interpreting the diagram in the obviously intended way). We would also have that the distance from $y$ to $x$ is strictly smaller than the distance from $z$ to $x$. It follows that $z\ne \hat y$. As $z$ was an arbitrary point in $M$, it follows that there is no element of $M$ that minimizes the distance to $x$.

Note that $M$ is an *open* line segment; $M$ does not contain the endpoints of the line segment, which is what pushes through the foregoing argument.  Things here are entirely analogous to the statement "the interval $(0,1)$ has no smallest element".